# Periodically delete data from firebase in certain time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to clear data from Firebase database every 24 hours, but I do not want to do this from code in my project, but from the Firebase.

Do firebase have such functions?

Comment: use cloud functions.

Comment: You can use cron job for this. please watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Please use the functions from [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment. There's no need to manage and scale your own servers.

Hope it helps.